# You don't have permission to read the archive in console.cloud.google.com

Tags: function, permissions, cloud

When I try to get source of function in console.cloud.google.com -

I got an error:
You don't have permission to read the archive

What I have to do to get permission?

Comment: Same issue here, maybe they have some problems

Comment: Same issue  ... !!

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I couldn't access my Cloud Function because my free trial was up. Apparently they lock you out of your own work so be careful. Luckily, the include some Cloud Function calls as part of the free tier, so I clicked to upgrade and was able to access them. This, after I chatted with support about granting me access.. it was billing support, the only support available by chat on the free trial., so they didn't really know, but I didnt get an email from support like they said I would, so I went and tried again.